# How to grep information for twitter?

Tags: linux, grep

I'd like to get the output "**tester123**" if I have the following input:

```
[{"id":4133554,"id_str":"445444","name":"tester123","screen_name":"whatelse"}]
```

Is that possible with the grep command?

Comment: I think the`sed` command along with some regex may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thx :] Do you have an idea referred to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you said grep, but your input is clearly JSON which grep is not really equipped to parse. You could use a quick Python solution:

```python
import json
inText = '[{"id":4133554,"id_str":"445444","name":"tester123","screen_name":"whatelse"}]'
data = json.loads(inText)
print data[0]['name']
```

You could get input in other ways based on your input format. For example, by reading from a file or via stdin:

```python
# Input file
with open('file.json') as fp:
     inText = fp.read()
# stdin
inText = raw_input()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -o '"name":"[^]]*'|cut -d\" -f4
```